# New navigation UI issue

Tags: bug, new-nav

Browser - Chrome

Screen resolution - 1366 x 768

The down arrow key position is not good in my browser view. I have marked with red color.

[image]

Comment: Zoom? I can repro zooming out

Comment: @Cai Yes you are right the browser was zoom out. My bad. Thanks